# Reading from serial port affecting values

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm having a little headache trying to read properly from the `SerialPort` class.

If I use the blocking method `ReadLine` or `ReadExisting` the aplication works like charm, but some of my values get affected because of the `string` conversion. I.e: the `0xFC` byte shows as `0x3F` ("?"). My guess is that any value outside of the ASCII scope will get lost too.

I tried using the `Read(byte[] buffer,int offset,int count)` method using the `SerialPort.ReadBufferSize` to see how many bytes I was supposed to read, but it is always returning almost 5000 , even when I'm trying to read only like 8 bytes from the UART. I had to create a function to trim this array to smaller one and the use it. I could use this method even though it's not efficient, but I sometimes get array out of bounds execution error using it. After debugging I found out this happens when I read a full array of zeroes.

My last try was using this code:

```
private void DataRec(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    byte[] myarray = new byte[200];
    int pos = 0;
    bool eol = false;
    while (!eol)
    {
        myarray[pos++] = (byte) sp.ReadByte();
        if (myarray[pos] == 0x7E) eol = true;
    }

    byte[] newarray = Recorta(myarray);
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new AtualizaCallBack(this.atualiza), new object[] { newarray });
    sp.DataReceived -= DataRec;
}
```

When debugging this I never get to the `byte[] newarray = Recorta(myarray);` breakpoint, no errors though. A weird thing is that whenever the event is fired again (I tell the UART to send me a packet) the `pos` variable does not start a zero.

Any ideas of what could be happening?

Some thing worth mentioning:

- 0x7E "~" is my end of line character
- 200 is the maximum amount of bytes I'll ever receive at one time
- The UART code is sending data one byte at a time, but only after receiving a proper request

Comment: `FC` *is* outside of the ASCII range... possibly that is just an encoding wobble? but yes, using the `byte`-based API should be more reliable. Are you checking whether `ReadByte()` returns something negative? (which would indicate EOF)

Comment: Marc, thanks for the input. That was my suspicion as well... As for the EOF, it is 0x7E "~" as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just using the wrong members of the SerialPort class.  ReadLine() and ReadExisting() return strings, but your data cannot be stored in a string.  There is no ASCII character code for 0xFC so it just gives up and produces the "cannot convert that byte" value.  Which is 0x3F, a question mark.

Similarly, ReadBufferSize is a fixed number, unless you reassign the value.  It sets the size of the buffer that the serial port driver uses to store received bytes before your program reads it.  At best you'd be interested in the BytesToRead property.  Which tells you how many bytes are available for reading inside that buffer.

Just use the SerialPort.Read() method.  And be sure to pay attention to its return value, it tells you how many bytes were read.  Which is almost always a small number, typically one or two bytes.  Serial ports are slow.  You'll need to keep reading until you got the device's full response.  In your case when you got that 0x7E.

Comment: Just want to emphasize for the OP (not for Hans) - `BytesToRead` should never be used to check for complete messages - it should *only* be used to determine if more data is available *synchronously* (which is largely unrelated to *messages*) - for example, to decide between a sync vs async read. Most times that I see people use `BytesToRead` / `DataAvailable` / etc - it is being used inappropriately.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'll try using the `BytesToRead` now and see what happens...

And my device is not really serial. I'm using the USB port, so I don't think speed is gonna be a problem. Maybe in this case the `BytesToRead` will save me.

Comment: Don't use BytesToRead, it is liable to get you into trouble because it is a constantly changing value.  Use the return value of Read() instead.

Comment: But then how can I know the proper size of the array beforehand?

On another note, using BytesToRead kinda worked. I'm not stuck inside the handler anymore. The first read works perfectly, but after that I get erroneous data (either miss the first byte or get a partial of last read).

Comment: You should know the *maximum* size of a response.  Just make your array big enough to store it.  If you don't then use a `List<Byte>` instead.  Having this kind of "miss the first byte" problem is *exactly* why you should not use BytesToRead.  It goes wrong when you use it twice, the second time it can be larger.

Comment: Just tried this:
`byte[] buffer = new byte[200];
            int count = sp.Read(buffer, 0, 200);

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new AtualizaCallBack(this.atualiza), new object[] { buffer.Take(count).ToArray() })`

Still having problems after the first read.

Comment: Sigh, you keep ignoring the advice.  Don't process the response until you got the *entire* response.  Which for one means that you'll have to store *buffer* in a field of your class, it cannot be a local variable.  And of course you will have to add the code that checks that 0x7e was received.  This was all mentioned in the answer, please read it again.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. It seems clearer now. I guess I'll have to manage the unsubscribe elsewhere as well to do this properly, otherwise I'd never get the full message. Gonna modify my class so I can store the buffer and search for the EOM.

Comment: After the proper modifications as you instructed it is now working as intended. Thanks a lot, Hans. My understanding of SerialPort communication just got a little better thanks to you :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think mostly you hadn't implemented it correctly.

```
    private byte[] ReadLine(SerialPort serialPort)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int count = 0;

        for (; count < buffer.Length; count++)
        {
            buffer[count] = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();
            if (buffer[count] == 0x7E) break;
        }

        return buffer.Take(count);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't quite work as I expected. Used Hans method. But thanks for remembering me about the `Take`. Although you missed a `.ToArray()` at the end.

Otherwise it gets a compiler error.